# How to create a dashed line in HMM

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code describe a hidden Markov process. Can someone tell me how to add a dashed line between the two rows of the circles, that is, a dashed line separate the observed space and the latent space? It would be better if the height of the whole picture does not change.

The following code is what I currently have while the picture is what is desired.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{}
\author{Author}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{main}=[circle, minimum size = 5mm, thick, draw =black!80, node distance = 10mm]
\tikzstyle{connect}=[-latex, thick]
\tikzstyle{box}=[rectangle, draw=black!100]
  \node[box,draw=white!100] (Latent) {\textbf{Latent}};
  \node[main] (L1) [right=of Latent] {$L_1$};
  \node[main] (L2) [right=of L1] {$L_2$};
  \node[main] (L3) [right=of L2] {$L_3$};
  \node[main] (Lt) [right=of L3] {$L_t$};
  \node[box,draw=white!100] (Observed) [below=of Latent] {\textbf{Observed}};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (O1) [right=of Observed,below=of L1] {$O_1$};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (O2) [right=of O1,below=of L2] {$O_2$};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (O3) [right=of O2,below=of L3] {$O_3$};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (Ot) [right=of O3,below=of Lt] {$O_t$};
  \path (L3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (Lt);
  \path (L1) edge [connect] (L2)
        (L2) edge [connect] (L3)
        (L3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (Lt);
  \path (O1) edge [connect] (O2)
        (O2) edge [connect] (O3)
        (O3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (Ot);
  \path (L1) edge [connect] (O1);
  \path (L2) edge [connect] (O2);
  \path (L3) edge [connect] (O3);
  \path (Lt) edge [connect] (Ot);
  \draw[dashed]  [below=of L1,above=of O1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small rearrangement for better placement of the `Observed` node, and using the `calc` library to ensure a horizontal line.

Also note that the positioning keys are not "cumulative", if you say `left=of a, below=of b`, the `left` key is ignored. That doesn't make a difference for your example though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,arrows,automata,calc}
\tikzset{
  main/.style={circle, minimum size = 5mm, thick, draw =black!80, node distance = 10mm},
  connect/.style={-latex, thick},
  box/.style={rectangle, draw=black!100}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[box,draw=white!100] (Latent) {\textbf{Latent}};
  \node[main] (L1) [right=of Latent] {$L_1$};
  \node[main] (L2) [right=of L1] {$L_2$};
  \node[main] (L3) [right=of L2] {$L_3$};
  \node[main] (Lt) [right=of L3] {$L_t$};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (O1) [below=of L1] {$O_1$};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (O2) [below=of L2] {$O_2$};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (O3) [below=of L3] {$O_3$};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (Ot) [below=of Lt] {$O_t$};
  \node[box,draw=white!100,left=of O1] (Observed) {\textbf{Observed}};
  \path (L3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (Lt);
  \path (L1) edge [connect] (L2)
        (L2) edge [connect] (L3)
        (L3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (Lt);
  \path (O1) edge [connect] (O2)
        (O2) edge [connect] (O3)
        (O3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (Ot);
  \path (L1) edge [connect] (O1);
  \path (L2) edge [connect] (O2);
  \path (L3) edge [connect] (O3);
  \path (Lt) edge [connect] (Ot);

  % draw the dashed line
  \draw [dashed, shorten >=-1cm, shorten <=-1cm]
      ($(Latent)!0.5!(Observed)$) coordinate (a) -- ($(Lt)!(a)!(Ot)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A little addition to your code makes this line (croked line fixed)

[image: mid]

```
    \documentclass{article}

\title{}
\author{Author}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,arrows,automata}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (8.5,2.5);
\tikzstyle{main}=[circle, minimum size = 5mm, thick, draw =black!80, node distance = 10mm]
\tikzstyle{connect}=[-latex, thick]
\tikzstyle{box}=[rectangle, draw=black!100]
  \node[box,draw=white!100] (Latent) {\textbf{Latent}};
  \node[main] (L1) [right=of Latent] {$L_1$};
  \node[main] (L2) [right=of L1] {$L_2$};
  \node[main] (L3) [right=of L2] {$L_3$};
  \node[main] (Lt) [right=of L3] {$L_t$};
  \node[box,draw=white!100] (Observed) [below=of Latent] {\textbf{Observed}};
    \node[main,fill=black!10] (O1) [right=of Observed,below=of L1] {$O_1$};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (O2) [right=of O1,below=of L2] {$O_2$};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (O3) [right=of O2,below=of L3] {$O_3$};
  \node[main,fill=black!10] (Ot) [right=of O3,below=of Lt] {$O_t$};
  \path (L3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (Lt);
  \path (L1) edge [connect] (L2)
        (L2) edge [connect] (L3)
        (L3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (Lt);
  \path (O1) edge [connect] (O2)
        (O2) edge [connect] (O3)
        (O3) -- node[auto=false]{\ldots} (Ot);
  \path (L1) edge [connect] (O1);
  \path (L2) edge [connect] (O2);
  \path (L3) edge [connect] (O3);
  \path (Lt) edge [connect] (Ot);
  \draw[dashed]  [below=of L1,above=of O1];

\path (Latent) -- (Observed) coordinate[midway](l44);
\node (l43) [left=of l44] {};
\path (Lt) -- (Ot) coordinate[midway](l444);
\node (l433) [right=of l444] {};
\draw[dashed,thick] (l43) to ++(0:180);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do to the placement of `Observed` your line is a bit crooked.

Comment: I know that code of the dashed line is a bit "hand-made", so I am happy if I get adequate advises and/or corrections.